# Construct (N+1)-dimensional diagonal matrix from values in N-dimensional array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array, diagonal

I have an N-dimensional array.  I want to expand it to an (N+1)-dimensional array by putting the values of the final dimension in the diagonal.

For example, using explicit looping:

```
In [197]: M = arange(5*3).reshape(5, 3)

In [198]: numpy.dstack([numpy.diag(M[i, :]) for i in range(M.shape[0])]).T
Out[198]: 
array([[[ 0,  0,  0],
        [ 0,  1,  0],
        [ 0,  0,  2]],

       [[ 3,  0,  0],
        [ 0,  4,  0],
        [ 0,  0,  5]],

       [[ 6,  0,  0],
        [ 0,  7,  0],
        [ 0,  0,  8]],

       [[ 9,  0,  0],
        [ 0, 10,  0],
        [ 0,  0, 11]],

       [[12,  0,  0],
        [ 0, 13,  0],
        [ 0,  0, 14]]])
```

which is a 5×3×3 array.

My actual arrays are large and I would like to avoid explicit looping (hiding the looping in `map` instead of a list comprehension has no performance gain; it's still a loop).  Although `numpy.diag` works for constructing a regular, 2-D diagonal matrix, it does not extend to higher dimensions (when given a 2-D array, it will extract its diagonal instead).  The array returned by `numpy.diagflat` makes everything into one big diagonal, resulting in a 15×15 array which has far more zeroes and cannot be reshaped into 5×3×3.

Is there a way to efficiently construct an (N+1)-diagonal matrix from the values in a N-dimensional array, without calling `diag` many times?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`numpy.diagonal`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.diagonal.html#numpy.diagonal) to take a view of the relevant diagonals of a properly-shaped N+1-dimensional array, force the view to be writeable with [`setflags`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.setflags.html), and write to the view:

```
expanded = numpy.zeros(M.shape + M.shape[-1:], dtype=M.dtype)

diagonals = numpy.diagonal(expanded, axis1=-2, axis2=-1)
diagonals.setflags(write=True)

diagonals[:] = M
```

This produces your desired array as `expanded`.

Answer (score 4):

You can use an almost-impossible-to-guess-if-you-don't-know feature of the ubiquitous `np.einsum`. When used as follows `einsum` will return a writable view of the generalized diagonal:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> M = np.arange(5*3).reshape(5, 3)
>>> 
>>> out = np.zeros((*M.shape, M.shape[-1]), M.dtype)
>>> np.einsum('...jj->...j', out)[...] = M
>>> out
array([[[ 0,  0,  0],
        [ 0,  1,  0],
        [ 0,  0,  2]],

       [[ 3,  0,  0],
        [ 0,  4,  0],
        [ 0,  0,  5]],

       [[ 6,  0,  0],
        [ 0,  7,  0],
        [ 0,  0,  8]],

       [[ 9,  0,  0],
        [ 0, 10,  0],
        [ 0,  0, 11]],

       [[12,  0,  0],
        [ 0, 13,  0],
        [ 0,  0, 14]]])
```

Comment: That's pretty close to magic to me.  Both your and user2357112's answer are correct, I have accepted user2357112's answer because I understand what's going on there :)

Answer (score 0):

A general way to turn the last dimension of a N-D array into a diagonal matrix:

We will need to reduce the dimensionality of the array, apply the `numpy.diag()` function to each vector, and then rebuild that to the original dimensionality + 1.

reshaping the matrix to 2 dimensional:

```
M.reshape(-1, M.shape[-1])
```

then use `map` to apply `np.diag` to that, and rebuild the matrix with an additional dimension using the following:

```
result.reshape([*M.shape, M.shape[-1]])
```

All of this combined gives the following:

```
result = np.array(list(map(
   np.diag,
   M.reshape(-1, M.shape[-1])
))).reshape([*M.shape, M.shape[-1]])
```

An example:

```
shape = np.arange(2,8)
M = np.arange(shape.prod()).reshape(shape)
print(M.shape)  # (2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7)

result = np.array(list(map(np.diag, M.reshape(-1, M.shape[-1])))).reshape([*M.shape, M.shape[-1]])

print(result.shape)  # (2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 7)
```

and `res[0,0,0,0,2,:]` contains the following:

```
array([[14,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0, 15,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0, 16,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0, 17,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0, 18,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 19,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 20]])
```

Comment: That is essentially what I'm currently doing with the list comprehension instead of `map`.  However, this still calls `diag` many times (`shape[:-1].prod()` times), which is what I'm trying to avoid for performance reasons.  This proposed solution offers no improvement over the approach in the question.

Comment: @gerrit I disagree with the last part of your comment: the approach in the question can only handle 2-D arrays as input, where this solution handles arrays of any dimension larger than 1.